# Android Programatically Close Out App1 and Start App2 from App1

Tags: android

My app needs to close itself out but before doing so initiate the startup of another app.  What is the best way to 1) issue startup request of second app (via broadcast or just startup activity), and 2) what is the best way to close out the first app.  Finish comes to mind but I want to close out the whole app and not just the current activity.  Thanks

Comment: Please note I have already read the answer "why would you want to do this Android manages this and will close it when it sees fit"  My Intention is clear, I want to get to an unlaunched state where  the user needs to launch the application to see any part of it again.  Yes I do need to close the application and close means close.  I don't want any of the activities to reappear until the user launches the app again.

Answer (score 1):

Just before closing your application you can fire an intent like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, package name of application 2); 
startAcvity(intent);
```

this will launch application 2 via an intent call.

as for closing application 1 goes have a look at the following link

[Finish sub activities programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544291/finish-sub-activities-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent res = new Intent();

/* Another App Package name*/

String mPackage = "com.ReachOut";

/* Class name */

String mClass = ".splash1";

res.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mPackage+mClass));

startActivity(res);
}
});

&  here u want to finish() your first App Activity .